# On sorting of Java's Priority Queue, clarification needed

Tags: java, priority-queue

Please help me understand something

I am starting with a

```
private Queue<SomeEvent> future = 
         new PriorityQueue(CAPACITY, new SomeEventComparatorByTime());
```

I then add 5 events (from group 1) to the queue, where each event starts at 10:49:00.

```
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid1'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid2'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid3'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid4'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid5'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
```

I then through some simple logic break events down by 2, incrementing times to be as follows. This printout shows current content of a queue.

```
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid1'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid2'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid3'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:50:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid4'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:50:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid5'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:51:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
```

At the end, i end up with sorted list of `SomeEvent` by time. This precise allocation is expected.

I then add 3 more events (from group 2) to the same queue. These events also start at 10:49:00

After i add events to queue, i get:

```
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid1'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid2'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_2_uid4'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_2_uid6'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid5'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:51:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid3'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:50:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_2_uid5'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:49:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
 ScheduledEvent{ userId='group_1_uid4'} { startTime=3/31/2013 10:50:00, repeat=RUN_ONCE }
```

Note that order is ... not sorted here. Why? I thought that as new element is added to queue, it's position is determined by the comparator

```
    for (SomeEvent e : group.getEvents()) {
        future.offer(e);
    }
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: How are you getting the current contents of the PriorityQueue? Popping the elements one by one or just trying to get a dump of the current state of the queue?

Comment: From the javadoc, "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is _not_ guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order." You using an `Iterator` per chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

"The Iterator provided in method iterator() is *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())."

You can also `poll` the elements one by one to get the correct order.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed i overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need check the logic in SomeEventComparatorByTime

Or Override the method compareTo in class SomeEvent and Implements Comparable

In this case you not need use the comparator

and just to say

private Queue future = new PriorityQueue();